# node.js & mysql - How to get the last inserted ID?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, lastinsertid

```
db.query("INSERT INTO `chat_entries`(`author`, `authorRank`, `receiver`, `timestamp`, `message`) VALUES (" + db.escape(GetUsername(connection)) + ", " + GetUserData(GetUsername(connection), "rank") + ", '-', " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + ", '" + db.escape(messageData.message) + "')", function(result, rows){
    console.log(result.insertId);
});
```

The console told me:

> Cannot read property 'insertId' of null

After I had searched for a solution I found this page:
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row

According to this documentation, it must work.
Where's my mistake?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an autoincrement column?

Comment: you should have an error-first callback

Answer (score 2):

you need to replace

```
console.log(result.insertId);
```

with

```
console.log(rows.insertId);
```

since it's the varibale you're passing to the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

Your callback params are wrong. Try this:

```
db.query("INSERT INTO `chat_entries`(`author`, `authorRank`, `receiver`, `timestamp`, `message`) VALUES (" + db.escape(GetUsername(connection)) + ", " + GetUserData(GetUsername(connection), "rank") + ", '-', " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + ", '" + db.escape(messageData.message) + "')", function (err, result) {
    console.log(result.insertId);
});
```

Comment: With this params I got the same message.

Comment: what do you get if you log just the `result` object?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, the first argument of the call back is error, and the second is the result.

You may also want to use placeholders for those dynamic values rather than concatenating them.

Moreover, do not hardcode single quote while using db.escape().

```
db.query("INSERT INTO table (`field1`, `field2`)
          VALUES ('Hello', " + db.escape("There") + ")",
         function(error, result) { });
```

Comment: Care to share link to documentation?